# Is it possible to set tests to continuously run on Android Studio?

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, continuous-testing, infinitest

I'd like to know if it is possible to do continuous testing on Android Studio.
I've found the Infinitest tool for Eclipse/IntelliJ but couldn't find any tools for Android Studio.
Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ I thought that there could be a way to do it on Android Studio too. 
Has anyone been able to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I couldn't find Facets in Project Structure in AS!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Infinitest has an IntelliJ plugin now. After a quick search, [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3146-infinitest) came up.

Alternatively, you could use command line tools to accomplish this. Use something like [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) to observe file changes and then have it execute your gradle test task.

Comment: Infinitest doesn't work on Android Studio. It's only "compatible" with it in the sense that you can install the plugin - not actually use it for anything.